# Optimizing joining a small table with a large table with dask.distributed

Tags: python, dask

Given, I have a distributed cluster:

```
import distributed
import dask
(distributed.__version__, dask.__version__)

('1.12.1', '0.11.0')

import dask
from distributed import Executor, progress
import dask.dataframe as dd
e = Executor('127.0.0.1:8786',set_as_default=True)
e

<Executor: scheduler="127.0.0.1:8786" processes=2 cores=64>
```

I create a large distributed dataframe and a small dataframe and persist it to a the cluster:

```
large_df = dd.read_csv('s3://bucket/*.csv', parse_dates=['date']) #test is about 50gb
small_df = dd.read_csv('s3://new_bucket/combined_driver_cleaned.csv',blocksize=None) #about 2 gb
large_df = e.persist(large_df)
small_df = e.persist(small_df)
```

In order for the merge step to go faster, i then replicate the small dataframe accross all workers

```
e.replicate(small_df)
```

`e.replicate` quickly returns.

and then the join step:

```
joined = e.persist(large_df.merge(small_df, how='inner', on='join_col'))
del large_df
```

At this point, weird things start happening. The bokeh plots show no activity and is stuck at 0/251 merge tasks. The worker logs show the following:

```
   Sep 07 12:43:55  conda[41833]: distributed.core - INFO - Connection from xx.xxx.xxx.xx:48522 to Worker
```

The ip address is the scheduler machine in the above connection. I suspect this is due to the `e.replicate` command. 
and i can see that the memory of the worker node slowly grows (top command output):

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
41944 root      20   0  0.175t 0.165t   6104 S 105.3 70.6   9:03.16 dask-work+
```

This is using 70% of 240gb of memory while both of my dataframes are much smaller in comparison.

what is the recommended way of doing something like this? I believe the replication is taking up all the space and a long time. Am i doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Surprising that `e.replicate` returns quickly.  It should block until all workers have `small_df`.

Comment: I'm unable to diagnose this without additional information.  I'm able to go through similar workflows very quickly (I just merged 60GB against a small table in 4s).  I recommend posting a reproducible example as a github issue.  If you need fake data then I recommend `dd.demo.make_timeseries`